# vocative comma by default

Tags: commas, speech, vocatives

If I say, "I will go skiing Nonna....." By default are the words preceding Nonna being addressed to Nonna? Or can I argue that my words preceding Nonna are not being addressed to Nonna, but rather, I say the word Nonna to get her attention so that she listens to what I say after her name.

Basically my question is- if we follow a sentence with someone's name while we are speaking, by default, are all the words preceding a person's name addressed to this name? Or is this too broad of a conclusion to make? I am asking because my character has Tourette's and has a habit of saying Nonna after speaking. Can I make the case that by saying Nonna or anyone's name after making a statement, you are not automatically employing the vocative comma and you are not 100% by default stating that the words preceding Nonna are being addressed to Nonna? How can I make this argument or is this argument even valid?

Comment: Both of your ideas of addressing Nonna and getting her attention are the same ... you are speaking to her. However, "skiing Nonna" means to travel to a mountain named Nonna for the sake of using skis. You need the comma to signal the name.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin: 'Ski' is now transitive?!

Comment: in the same sense that 'Hike' is (i.e. hike a mountain)

Comment: Hike, ski, climb the Matterhorn. Usually preceded by *the.*

Comment: haha, yes I see how the sentence changes without a comma. In general though, If I say (not write) a series of words and then randomly say a person's name afterwards, one cannot assume that the words preceding the name were addressed to that person? Or by default does everything before and after the person's name become addressed to that person?

Comment: "What is the highest mountain in the Urals [looks around the class] John?"